# How to called this.getRowStyle function forcefully in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using getRowStyle function, but it seems it runs only once when the grid is loaded or it is edited. How do I force run this function manually so that row colors are loaded.

```
conditonalFormatter() {
    this.GridRef.rowConditionalFormatting('red', this.rowFormatData);
}

rowConditionalFormatting(rowColor, rowFormatData) {
    this.rowFormatData = rowFormatData;
    this.getRowStyle = params => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rowFormatData.length; i++) {
                const columnHeader = this.rowFormatData[i].Name;
                const operator = this.rowFormatData[i].Operator;
                const cellValue = this.rowFormatData[i].Value;
                if (params.data[columnHeader] == cellValue) {
                    return {background: rowColor };
                }
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: @Batajus - Please refer abv functon. it get works during on-load but If I called this funntion from somewhere else then this.getRowStye won't get called.

Comment: Can you also share the code snippets where you're calling `this.getRowStyle`

Comment: @Batajus I have called this from diff component by using referance. Thanks.

Comment: Did u try `rowClassRules` ?

Comment: I need to pass dynamic color as well as values where I need to do RowStyle so can't use rowClassRules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually apply the row styling again, then you will need to refresh Aggrid manually with refreshCells().

Generally, only those rows where data is changed is redrawn and other rows are ignored. In your case, we will need to force aggrid to redraw the rows and hence will have to use `force=true`

```
gridApi.refreshCells({
      force: true // skips change detection -> always refreshes the row
   })
```

You will get gridApi object, in onGridReady callback provided by aggrid.

```
public onGridReady(params) {
    /**
    * Function is called when grid is instantiated.
    * @param params Ag grid params
    */
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine" [columnDefs]="columnDefs [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

After several try I am able to acheive my objective as per below code, just call this.getRowStyle outside -

```
rowConditionalFormatting(rowColor, rowFormatData) {
   this.rowFormatData = rowFormatData;
   this.rowColor = rowColor;    
}

 this.getRowStyle = params => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rowFormatData.length; i++) {
        const columnHeader = this.rowFormatData[i].Name;
        const operator = this.rowFormatData[i].Operator;
        const cellValue = this.rowFormatData[i].Value;
        if (params.data[columnHeader] == cellValue) {
            return {background: this.rowColor };
        }
    }    
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The code above is __not calling__ `this.getRowStyle`, it's __defining the function__ as _lambda expression_. In this expression the properties of `this.rowFormatData` are  evaluated and return a style dynamically based on matching `params.data[columnHeader]` (i.e. the current cell-value).

Comment: this.getRowStyle itself a function, it called automatically. print params inside console and check. Ref - https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-styles/